# Scikit-learn categorisation: binomial log regression?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

I have texts that are rated on a continous scale from -100 to +100. I am trying to classify them as positive or negative.

How can you perform binomial log regression to get the probability that test data is -100 or +100?

The closest I have got is the SGDClassifier( penalty='l2',alpha=1e-05, n_iter=10), but this doesn't provide the same results as [SPSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPSS) when I use binomial log regression to predict the probability of -100 and +100. So I'm guessing this is not the right function?

Comment: may be it's better to ask this at http://datascience.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I don't think the sklearn implementations of logistic regression can deal with probabilistic targets. They only do labels. It would be cool to have that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SGDClassifier provides access to several linear classifiers, all trained with stochastic gradient decent. It will default to a linear support vector machine, unless you call it with a different loss function.  loss='log' will provide a probabilistic logistic regression.

See the documentation at:
 http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Alternatively, you could use sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression to classify your texts with a logistic regression.

It's not clear to me that you will get exactly the same results as you do with SPSS due to differences in implementation. However, I would not expect to see statistically significant differences.

Edited to add:

My suspicion is that the 99% accuracy you're getting with the SPSS logistic regression is training set accuracy, while the 87% that you're seeing with scikits-learn logistic regression is test set accuracy. I found this question on the datascience stack exchange where a different person is attempting and extremely similar problem, and getting ~99% accuracy on training sets and 90% test set accuracy.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/987/text-categorization-combining-different-kind-of-features

My recommended path forwards is a follows: Try several different basic classifiers in scikits-learn, including the standard logistic regression and a linear SVM, and also rerun the SPSS logistic regression several times with different train/test subsets of your data and compare the results. If you continue to see a large divergence across classifiers that can't be accounted for by ensuring similar train/test data splits, then post the results that you're seeing into your question, and we can move forward from there.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to `SGDClassifier( penalty='l2', alpha=1e-05, n_iter=10, loss='log')`. However, how do I get it to only find the probability data is in a -100 or +100 class? Do I only feed it with training data labelled as either -100 or +100? Or is there an attribute I should set?

Comment: I believe i can answer your question. After dinner if possible, if not then later tonight after the kids go to bed.

Comment: Great! Looking forward to it.

Comment: I think i need some clarification here. What are the features and labels on this data, and what are you trying to find? My understanding is that the data is text, the features are a +100 to -100 range, and you are trying to use a logistic regression, not merely to classify +1 / -1, but you also want the probability that each text is in each class. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to binary classify data as either negative -1 or positive +1. The data is tweets that have been rated from -100 to +100. The features are TF-IDF for the tweets.
I was tried all the classifiers in scikit-learn but am not getting the same accuracy I get in SPSS. In Scikit-learn I get around 0.87 precision. In SPSS I get 0.99 for the same data and splits. The SPSS method that I use tries to calculate the probability a tweet is -100 or +100, and provides a probability.

Comment: How are you segmenting the data into train/test/validate sets, and how were you doing it under SPSS? Are you comparing training set performance to test set performance?

Comment: Also, what type of regularization did you use in SPSS?

Comment: In SPSS you specify either your required number or proportion of each set. The machine then chooses the three sets according to your specification at random. At the start you have to enter a seed for the random number generator. Then to get replicable results you must keep the same seed - or it will generated different random numbers and thus different results. I didn't do any regularization.

Comment: A few more questions:
Have you tried multiple classifiers under scikits-learn, and compared their results against the SPSS method? I would recommend quickly trying the LogisticRegression, and an SVM with a linear kernel. 
How many times did you run the classification in SPSS? is the 99% accuracy from a single run, or the average across multiple runs?
What happens when you run the LR in SPSS 10 times, run the SGDC 10 times (with randomly selected train/test/validate sets), and run the sckikits Logistic Regression and Linear SVM 10 times each? How do those compare?

Answer (score 0):

If pos/neg, or the probability of pos, is really the only thing you need as output, then you can derive binary labels `y` as

```
y = score > 0
```

assuming you have the scores in a NumPy array `score`.

You can then feed this to a `LogisticRegression` instance, using the continuous score to derive relative weights for the samples:

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
sample_weight = np.abs(score)
sample_weight /= sample_weight.sum()
clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight)
```

This gives maximum weight to tweets with scores ±100, and a weight of zero to tweets that are labeled neutral, varying linearly between the two.

If the dataset is very large, then as @brentlance showed, you can use `SGDClassifier`, but you have to give it `loss="log"` if you want a logistic regression model; otherwise, you'll get a linear SVM.